# $\LaTeX$ Symbol for a right-angled triangle

Tags: support, mathjax

Is there a $\LaTeX$ symbol for a right-angled triangle, with the triangle lying on its right angle, either on the left or right?

There is $\triangle$, $\triangledown$, $\triangleleft$, $\triangleright$ but no right-angled triangle.

Any help would be appreciated. If there is none, perhaps some pointers on how to construct one.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know, but I know there's a tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65455/is-there-a-math-symbol-for-right-angled-triangle

Comment: Thanks for your input, Gerry and mixedmath. The link was very helpful, @mixedmath

Comment: I used a picture environment.  Unfortunately, answers are closed.  Hopefully this will paste right. \begin{picture}(7,7)
\put(1,6){\line(1,0){5}}
\put(1,6){\line(0,-1){5}}
\put(1,1){\line(1,1){5}}
\end{picture}
If the diagonal line doesn't print, you may need to add a \usepackage{pict2e} to the preamble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the "Mathematical Operators" section, we have

`\unicode{0x22BF}`$=\unicode{0x22BF}$ (RIGHT TRIANGLE)

As pointed out by hypergeometric, in the "Geometric Shapes" section, we also have

`\unicode{0x25FA}`$=\unicode{0x25FA}$ (LOWER LEFT TRIANGLE)
`\unicode{0x25FF}`$=\unicode{0x25FF}$ (LOWER RIGHT TRIANGLE)

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful! (+1)

Comment: After years, it is useful for me right now.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a note to myself.

\unicode{0x25FA}:   $\qquad\unicode{0x25FA}$

\unicode {0x22BF}:  $\qquad\unicode {0x22BF}$

Comment: So ... `\unicode` is recognized by Mathjax, but not by LaTeX.

Comment: It appears so. Had to change (...) to {...}.

Comment: (+1) I don't know how the parentheses crept into my answer. I thought I had simply copied the LaTeX, but I guess in removing the backslashes, I made more of a change than I thought. I didn't see `0x25FA`. In the Unicode table, it looks a lot smaller. Good catch!

Comment: @robjohn - Thanks for pointing out the crucial step!